# Google Authorization Header Incorrect (401 Error)

Tags: oauth, google-api

Am trying to create a doc (very very basic) using 2-legged OAuth (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth) - in my web server.

Here's the code:

```
!* Clicked: Run Btn *

ThisWebClient.SetAllHeadersDefault()
ThisWebClient.HeaderOnly = 0
ThisWebClient.Host = 'http://docs.google.com'
ThisWebClient.ContentType = 'application/atom+xml'
ThisWebClient.Authorization = 'OAuth oauth_version="1.0", '&|
  'oauth_nonce="'&today()&clock()&'", '&|
  'oauth_timestamp="'&clock()&'", '&|
  'oauth_consumer_key="..google user content string..", '&|
  'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", '&|
  'oauth_signature="..signature string.."'
ThisWebClient.Post('https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full?xoauth_requestor_id=stu.a%40sandersnoonan.com',|
  '<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" '&|
  'term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#document" /><atom:title>SNIPS Stuff</atom:title></atom:entry>')
```

(screenshot taken, initially posted)

[image]

**I'm currently getting a 401 error, Unknown authorization header.**

-- This is my first go with OAuth and using Google APIs for development, so I might have missed something VERY simple.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please next time include your code as text in a code block and not as image.

Comment: Done. Included code. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`oauth_signature`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4) can't be hardcoded into your code. It is for each request calculated using HMAC-SHA1 and dependent on your timestamp, nonce, etc.

Google also has [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#SigningOAuth) for the signing step.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the info. I'm reading the "Signing OAuth requests" section on that page, and under number 2., 3rd point down , if I'm reading it right, then I use the Consumer Secret in my Google app "Keys" section. Which is what I did.

Comment: This does not mean, that `oauth_signature = CONSUMER_SECRET`, but that you have to use your constructed `base_string` and your `CONSUMER_SECRET` as input parameters for the `HMAC_SHA1` algorithmus. So in pseudocode something like: `oauth_signature = HMAC_SHA1(data = base_string, key = CONSUMER_SECRET)`

Comment: Ahhh! Okay, that makes sense. Thanks Jan, I'll give that a crack.